# How can I debug JavaScript code for a 'Free Coins' button click on agar.io?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm trying to find the JavaScript code that runs whenever you click a "Free Coins" button on agar.io. I've utilized the event listener of click and stuff to find the script im looking for but im confused.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jN0c.png)
The script is just a few lines long but the lines are huge themselves, they look obfuscated and minimized, how will i possibly debug this? I think this is the correct script. I do have the class of the button too "free-coins-button", so it should be easier to find the part where the mouseclick event is. Can anyone help?

I tried using the help of other answers here. I dont know how to do this in my specific case.